# What do we mean by familiar topology

Tags: general-topology

There is a problem in my text book ...Let $L$ be a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^2$,describe the topology $L$ inherits as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}$ and as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_l \times \mathbb{R}_l$, where $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the real line in the lower limit (Sorgenfrey) topology.

In each case it is a familiar topology. I have found out both the topologies with the help of my friend.But we don't know what is familiar topology.

Comment: "Familiar topology" means exactly what it sounds like: that it is a topology you've seen before (at least, you're supposed to have seen it), and therefore are familiar with.

Comment: What is $R_2$? Do you mean $\Bbb R^2$? And what is $Rl$? Do you mean $L$? Also can you Tex your questions in the future?

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: vertical and horizontal lines are homeomorphic to the axis space (so $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}_l$) they're parallel too. Lines with negative slope have the discrete topology in the Sorgenfrey plane, etc.

Comment: @Noah Riggenbach .Here Rl means lower limit topology in real line